# Add 'active' class to K2 Content Module Item

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I have searched to the end of the internet and cannot find an answer to this and my limited php knowledge is making this seemingly easy task very difficult.

The file is modules/mod_k2_content/templates/default/default.php around LINE 22

Here is the code:

```
<li id="" class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even";  if(count($items)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; ?>">
```

I simply need to add an 'active' to the class area **IF** the li is the page I am currently viewing in order to highlight it with CSS.

Comment: We could probably help you more if we knew what other variables are available and what they contain, e.g. some more of the code...

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in that, so we can read it...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check the standard joomla routing variables to do some checks. I don't use K2 much, so you may have to play with the values to get this working in your case:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$option = $jinput->get('option');
$view = $jinput->get('view');
$id = $jinput->get('id');
```

I would then compare those values to the items in the link that are likely in the code directly after the code that you have included. If all three match, you are on that page!

Comment: David, thanks for your answer, however I guess maybe I should have said I have VERY limited PHP knowledge instead of just limited lol... :( 

I sort of get what you're saying, but not to the point where I have the ability to make it work. Hopefully there is someone on here that is familiar with this K2 module.

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is correct you need to check for option,view and id and than add the class to li here is rest of the code -

```
<?php
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $option = $jinput->get('option');
    $view = $jinput->get('view');
    $id = $jinput->getInt('id'); ?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  
        $liclass = '';
        if(($option=='com_k2') && ($view=='item') && ($id==$item->id)){
            $liclass = 'active ';
        });
        ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $liclass?><?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; if(count($items)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; ?>">
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code:

```
<?php $id = JRequest::getVar('id'); ?>
<li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; if(count($items)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; echo ($id == $item->id)?" active":""; ?>">
```